# Skip dual boot selection screen after hibernation on Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, multi-boot, hibernate

When I wake the machine up from a Windows 7 hibernate, the boot selection screen comes up rather than starting the hibernate resume, and I have to select Windows 7 on the list. Is there any way to skip this screen on a hibernate resume so Windows 7 resumes automatically?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What are you dual booting with?

I got around this by using the Windows boot manager rather than grub to choose between Windows and Linux at the boot screen.

If Windows is in hibernation, it just resumes Windows. If the computer has been shut down, it offers me the choice.

Comment: This sounds like what I need to do. I assume I'm using Grub since Ubuntu was installed last. How can I switch boot managers?

Comment: Install grub in a partition rather than the MBR, use `dd` to create a file of the boot record of the partition, copy that file to your Windows boot partition and add it to the boot menu.

Then you can "repair" the Windows mbr.

Google will give you further details.